# How can I get a custom UITableView to automatically scroll to a selected text field?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a `UITableView`, which I am controlling from a custom `UIViewController`. When the user clicks the 'add' button, I add a row to the `UITableView` with a text field in it, and make it the first responder. The problem is, when the bottom of the table is out of view (or hidden by the keyboard), the `UITableView` doesn't scroll to bring the text field into view.

`UITableViewController` does this automatically, but my View Controller can't be a subclass of `UITableViewController`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scroll UITextField above Keyboard in a UITableViewCell on a regular UIViewController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036519/scroll-uitextfield-above-keyboard-in-a-uitableviewcell-on-a-regular-uiviewcontro)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I fixed this by twiddling `contentInset` on the `UITableView` when the keyboard appears or disappears.

```
- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasHidden:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    CGRect keyboardBounds;
    [[aNotification.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey] getValue: &keyboardBounds];
    keyboardHeight = keyboardBounds.size.height;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, keyboardBounds.size.height, 0);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[items count] inSection:0]
                     atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle
                             animated:YES];
}

- (void)keyboardWasHidden:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

call `registerForKeyboardNotifications` when you load the `UITableView`, and everything else should Just Work.

Comment: [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[items count] inSection:0]
                     atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle
                             animated:YES];   What do "items" mean here?

Comment: In case anyone's interested in how UIKit handles the animations in this case (I had the same problem), read here: http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/316466-resizing-uitableview-will-keeping-content-scrolled-to-bottom.html

Answer (score 0):

I found [`-scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW7) and guess this would do what you want.

Comment: It doesn't, because the `UITableView` is still the height of the whole screen (and covered by the keyboard).

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem, here's my soln: http://www.passiondeveloper.com/discussion/8/uitableview-inline-editing-with-a-textfield-inside-uitableview-not-scrolling-when-keyboard-is-shown

Answer (score 0):

work for ios5

```
UITextField *activeField;

// Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.

-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   activeField = textField;
}
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   activeField = nil;
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent

- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)aNotification {


   id view = [activeField superview];
   while (view && ![view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) 
   {
      view = [view superview];
   }
   UITableViewCell *cell = view;
   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableview indexPathForCell:cell];
   CGRect keyboardBounds;
   [[aNotification.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey] getValue: &keyboardBounds];
   [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
   [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
   tableview.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, keyboardBounds.size.height, 0);
   [UIView commitAnimations];
   [tableview scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];

}

- (void)keyboardWasHidden:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
   [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
   [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    tableview.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
   [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```