# Check UITextField is visible but behind the keyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, keyboard, uitextfield, show-hide

**Work around:**

`UIViewController`
 contains `UITableview` with custom cell. Each cell contains cusom `UIView` with `UITextField`.

We all know that it is possible to manage `UITextField` delegates and make `UIView` up/down to show `UITextField` that are not visible when keyboard appears.

**Problem:**

Here content of `UITableView` is dynamic, its decided runtime that which cell contains `UITextField`. 
I have tried many solution for keyboard up/down views. But still some issues remains.

So now decided to make a translation only for that `UITextField` which are not appear on screen or behind the keyboard.

Is there any way to know that
 `UITextField` which is responder of keyboard appearance is behind the keyboard or its above the keyboard?

Any better approach?

Please add a comment if question is unclear.

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036519/scroll-uitextfield-above-keyboard-in-a-uitableviewcell-on-a-regular-uiviewcontro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the current textField frame y position you can check is that is it behind the keyboard or not using

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    CGPoint textFieldPosition = [textField convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
}
```

now check the y value and move your UIVIew based on y value..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking all this you can reframe the tableView when keyboard is visible.

In `viewDidLoad()`  add this

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardShow) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
```

in receiver set the new frame

```
 - (void)keyboardShow{
        [tableView setFrame:newFrame]
    }
```

again in `name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification`  reset to initial frame when keyboard is not there