# How to scroll UITextView above Keyboard in a UITableView in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I found this solution for objective-c: [Scroll UITextField above Keyboard in a UITableViewCell on a regular UIViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036519/scroll-uitextfield-above-keyboard-in-a-uitableviewcell-on-a-regular-uiviewcontro) but I can't adapt it for swift.

```
func textViewShouldBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
    var pointInTable:CGPoint? =  textView.superview?.convertPoint(textView.frame.origin, toView: tableView)
    var contentOffset:CGPoint = tableView.contentOffset
    contentOffset.y  = pointInTable?.y - textView.inputAccessoryView?.frame.size.height
}
```

I get error :

```
Value of optional type 'CGFloat?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
```

When I use ! or ? I get error:
Operand of postfix '?' should have optional type; type is 'CGFloat'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is one way to avoid the error in your code:

```
func textViewShouldBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
    var pointInTable:CGPoint = textView.superview!.convertPoint(textView.frame.origin, toView: tableView)
    var contentOffset:CGPoint = tableView.contentOffset
    contentOffset.y  = pointInTable.y
    if let accessoryView = textView.inputAccessoryView {
        contentOffset.y -= accessoryView.frame.size.height
    }
    tableView.contentOffset = contentOffset
    return true
}
```

First of all, we can assume `textView` has a `superview`, so we can unwrap it with `!`.
As a result, `pointInTable` is not optional anymore.
If we assume `textView` might not have an `inputAccessoryView`, we can use the typical `if let` syntax to check if `inputAccessoryView` exists and, if so, subtract its height from `contentOffset.y`.
Don't forget to assign `contentOffset` to your `tableView` and return a `Bool`.

Comment: its moving too much.. can i make the distance of movement lesser??

Comment: @SaiPavanParanam absolutely! Please try different values of `contentOffset` until you find the one that suits you best.

Comment: @Para Great answer

Comment: @Para this code scrolls my textview to the very top of the screen rather than just above the keyboard. Can you advise on how this might be fixed? I know I can add static numbers to the contentOffset but I'm more interested in finding out why your code doesn't put it exactly above the keyboard?

Comment: @SaiPavanParanam did you figure this out?